# How we can pass command line argument in j2me application?

Tags: java-me

How we can pass command line argument in j2me application ?

Answer (score 5):

There is no "command line" to pass the arguments from. You need to design your program differently; ask the user at the start of the program for the information you need.

In general, J2ME is not used for the same kinds of things you would do with J2SE command-line programs. There is also no way (normally) for the user to view the standard output or to supply standard input. Study the MIDlet API carefully.

Answer (score 2):

As it is already answered that there is no way of passing 'command line' arguments for a MIDlet, there is a way in which you could do something similar using user defined attributes in JAD file. For example, if you are wanting to use values of ServerURL,UpdateURL in your application, then simply define the following in JAD file:

```
ServerURL: http://<somehost>:port/webcontext
UpdateURL: http://<somehost>:port/webcontext
```

And these properties can be accessed from the application by

```
String url = midlet.getAppProperty("ServerURL");
```

Now, these user defined attributes can be changed to your desired values whenever you want to, with no changes to your application. This is in a way equivalent to passing command line arguments.

However, it must be noted that if the application is signed, then make sure that the JAD properties that need to be modified after signing are excluded from the MANIFEST file. Otherwise, verification fails because properties in MANIFEST don't match with the ones found in JAD file.

Hope this answers your query.